# Getting an error in vroom file when I try to read in a CSV file

Tags: r, read-csv

I am getting a weird error message when I try to read my csv file into R. For some reason it is only when I try to read in this specific csv file that I get this error, otherwise my code works for other csv files.

I tried to do the read_csv function to bring my dataset in and I got this error.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your information in a *text* format, i.e. not as screenshots?